# How to retrieve sum of a column of data from the database?

Tags: java, database, swing

How to retrieve sum of a column of data from the database and subract it from another column of data from the database? I want to do it like, get the sum from Total_Sales column and sum from Total_Value column and perform subract operation ie, subract value of Total_Value from value of Total_Sales (Total_Sales - Total_Value).  Currently this is my piece of code.

```
calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");

        java.util.Date fromDate=(java.util.Date)fromtextField.getValue();
        java.util.Date toDate=(java.util.Date)totextField.getValue();

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select SUM(Total_Sales - Total_Value) As Result from DailyAnalysis where 'Date1 BETWEEN #fromDate# AND #toDate#' ");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            String itemName = rs.getString("Item");
            Double totalValue = rs.getDouble("Total_Value");
            Double totalSales = rs.getDouble("Total_Sales");

            Double Result = rs.getDouble(1);

        }

    }
    catch(SQLException s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException z)
    {
        System.out.println(z);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException n)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    }
    });
```

[image]

**EDITS**
I am trying to retrieve of the columns between two dates. I want to set the total of retrieved value of Total_Value to the Total Expense text field, and sum of Total_Sales column to the Total Income textfield. Then calculate the profit or loss based on that.

Comment: You haven't even been able to search for "sql" and "sum" on your favorite search engine?

Comment: Which database are we dealing with here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Sum(Total_Sales) as Sales_Total, Sum(Total_Value) as Value_Total, Sum(Total_Sales - Total_Value) as Result
From DailyAnalysis
```

Change query and code to this

```
     Double result = null;
     Double totalValue = null;
     Double totalSales = null;
      ...

      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select Sum(Total_Sales) as Sales_Total, Sum(Total_Value) as Value_Total, SUM(Total_Sales - Total_Value) As Result from DailyAnalysis where Date1 BETWEEN ? AND ? ");
            ps.setDate(1,fromDate)
            ps.setDate(2,toDate)
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            //Query should only return one or zero result hence the if statement
            if (rs.next())
            {  
               //Define variables at the top, if you want to have access outside the if block scope
               totalValue = rs.getDouble("Value_Total");
               totalSales = rs.getDouble("Sales_Total");
               result = rs.getDouble("Result");
            }
```

Comment: how can i retrieve that value if i do like that?

Comment: Double Result = rs.getDouble(1); using this still gives me the same error

Comment: @Toms I believe I have your problem nailed down. Do you need any more information, or are you satisfied?

Comment: perfect man... i got it in the way i wanted.. Thanks a lot !! ^_^

now if i set coding of print button, i am done with my project. got my submission at morning 7.30 am its already 2.30 am.